# $or doesn't work for subdocument level search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Search retrieves result only in parent level. search with $or condition returns empty array for subdocument level filter/search. $or doesn't work for subdocument level search. Any fixes for this or any mistakes in my code?

```
exports.getAllProduct = (req, res, next) => {
categories.find({$or:[{“categoryName”:{ $regex: req.params.id, $options: ‘i’ }},
{“subcategory.$.productName”:{ $regex: req.params.id, $options: ‘i’ }}]},
(err, products) => {
   console.log(“Products:“+JSON.stringify(products));
  if (err) {
         return res.status(400).json({
           error: “No Products found”+err
         });
       }
       res.status(200).json(products)
     });
};
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        categoryName: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        subcategory: [ {
            subcategoryName: {
                type: String,
                trim:true
            },
            productCode: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
            }]});
```

http://localhost:3000/category/getAllProduct/fruits

What mistake why $or is not working? I'm using mongoDB 4.4.1 and mongoose 5.10.8 and Mac OS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see sub-category is an array..you should check in the second parameter of the $or if the input is “$in” array.
Check this post
[MongoDB query IN array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298001/mongodb-query-in-array-of-object)

Comment: $in will be used to compare same field with different input's. but for mine the case is different i'm comparing different names like categoryName, SubcategoryName, productCode....the field names are different so it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your mongo query correctly, you have a `$` in `subcategory.$.subcategoryName` which is most likely causing the issue you are seeing. Use `subcategory.subcategoryName` to query against that value.

See below:

```
categories.find({
  $or:[
   {
     “categoryName”:{
       $regex: req.params.id,
       $options: 'i'  
     }
   },
   {
     “subcategory.subcategoryName”: {
       $regex: req.params.id,
       $options: 'i'
     }
   }
  ]},
  (err, products) => {}
);
```

Also, always try to format your code cleanly as in this example. It makes finding solutions easier.

If you do not need the query to be case insensitive the below query will be cleaner:

```
categories.find({
  $or:[
   {
     “categoryName”: req.params.id
   },
   {
     “subcategory.subcategoryName”: req.params.id
   }
  ]},
  (err, products) => {}
);
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick if i remove the $ sign as you said it is working but it is retrieving all documents in the subdocument array. only for the parent level filter is work for subdocument level it is fetching all records after removing $ sign but no records is getting fetched

Comment: say for example that there is a subdocument with subcategory name as test 1 , test 2 , test 3 .

Comment: “subcategory.subcategoryName”:  "test 1" // req.params.id
it should retrieve only test 1 from subdocument but it is retrieving all records from the subdocument array like test 1, test 2 , test 3